# Is there a risk in my design User in Django？

Tags: python, django

I am creating the extend User like bellow:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=40)  # sha1加密
    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11)  # 手机号码
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    qq = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)  # 地址

    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)


    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

You see there are two fields here:

```
is_staff = False
is_superuser = False
```

So, when I create the AdminUser, if there is a risk?
Because the hacker may use :

```
AdminUser(xxxxx, is_staff=True, is_superuser=True, xxx)
```

to create a superuser. Or whether my User model is complete wrong?

---

**EDIT**

The `AbstractUser` is `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser`.

Comment: If an attacker can run code in your application, then you don't need to worry about security anymore.

Comment: So that is what it is.

Comment: **Never** save the sha1 of a password, always use an appropriate password-based key derivation function such as bcrypt, argon or PBKDF2. In the case of Django's `AbstractUser`, just use `user.set_password(raw_password)`, and don't override the `password` field.

Comment: @knbk i have keep in mind, sir.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create the User Model from the scratch. [You can extend django's User model to add the additional fields you want.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user) It is the recommended way.

And, the recommended way to create a superuser (read as admin-user) is by [using django-admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser)

Comment: I am inherit from AbstractUser.

Comment: but you are overriding most of the fields.

Comment: just add the new fields